# Bootstrap not rendering

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, flask, pdfkit

The question is splitted in different section:

- Little preamble and sharing of the tries done
- Folder structure and code to reproduce the problem
- Showing and explaining the problem
- Questions

---

### Preamble

I have created a simple Flask 1.1.1 application with Python 3.8 on Raspbian.

I'm trying to implement the generation of PDF file using [PdfKit](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit), but I'm facing some problem with the bootstrap rendering.

I have alredy tried to search on google and I have found two articles:

- [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59772649/module-that-converts-html-to-pdf-module-compatible-with-bootstrap-and-flask) without usefull answer.
- [Second on github](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/issues/66) that refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039452/disable-media-print-in-bootstrap) but the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35039492/5532710) is not working (I have download the BS without the *Print media styles* checked). Reading in the comment someone point to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410724/bootstrap-print-css-removes-background-color/36742058#36742058) but is related to the background color.

As said in the repo README.md I has installed the static binary of wkhtmltopdf:

> Warning! Version in debian/ubuntu repos have reduced functionality
> (because it compiled without the wkhtmltopdf QT patches), such as
> adding outlines, headers, footers, TOC etc. To use this options you
> should install static binary from wkhtmltopdf site or you can use this
> script.

There is an option called `--user-style-sheet` to use as workaround for something:

> Warning This is a workaround for this bug in wkhtmltopdf. You should
> try --user-style-sheet option first.

The problem is that I don't know for which bug because the reference page is offline.

---

### Code and folder

The project folder structure is the following:

```
WebServer/
├── Rembe
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── content
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.css
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
│   │   ├── scripts
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.js
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── test_page.html
│   │   └── test_pdf_report.html
│   └── views.py
└── runserver.py
```

The code to reproduce the problem (avoid the bootstrap stuff, you can download it from the official website, I have the code from it):

****init**.py**

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

import Rembe.views
```

**runserver.py**

```py
from os import environ, path, walk
from Rembe import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Folder to monitor and check if the server needs to be reloaded
    extra_dirs = ['/home/pi/WebServer/', '/home/pi/WebServer/Rembe/', '/home/pi/WebServer/Rembe/templates/']
    extra_files = extra_dirs[:]
    for extra_dir in extra_dirs:
        for dirname, dirs, files in walk(extra_dir):
            for filename in files:
                filename = path.join(dirname, filename)
                if path.isfile(filename):
                    extra_files.append(filename)

    app.run('0.0.0.0', 80, False, extra_files=extra_files)
```

**views.py**

```py
from flask import render_template, url_for, send_from_directory
from Rembe import app
import pdfkit

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/test_page')
def test_page():
    return render_template(
        'test_page.html', title='test'
    )

@app.route('/test_view', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_view():
    return render_template('test_pdf_report.html', my_custom_value='TEST PARAMETER')

@app.route('/test_download', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_download():
    filename = 'report.pdf'

    string_page = render_template('test_pdf_report.html', my_custom_value='TEST PARAMETER')
    options = {'enable-local-file-access': ""}
    pdfkit.from_string(string_page, f'/tmp/{filename}')

    return send_from_directory(directory='/tmp/', filename=filename)
```

**test_page.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ title }} - TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/content/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container body-content">
        <a href="{{url_for('test_view')}}">test</a>
        <label> | </label>
        <a href="{{url_for('test_download')}}">Download</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**test_pdf_report.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='content/bootstrap.min.css', _external=True) }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2 style="text-align: center">REPORT TITLE - {{my_custom_value}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>ROW 1 - COLUMN 1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>ROW 1 - COLUMN 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>ROW 2 - COLUMN 1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>ROW 2 - COLUMN 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>ROW 3 - COLUMN 1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>ROW 3 - COLUMN 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### Problem

This project generate a white page with two clickable text: *test* and *download*

[image: ClickableText]

Clicking on the text **test** the rendered page is correct and the bootstrap correctly work, the rows/columns are in the right place.

[image: testImage]

Clicking on the text **Download** the pdf open but bootstrap is not rendered and the rows/columns are aligned to the left of the page.

[image: downloadImage]

The output of the server tell me all is good:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

I has also tried to generate the PDF directly with the `wkhtmltopdf` library as follow:

```
wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access test_pdf_report.html /tmp/mypdf.pdf
```

The command execute and generate the PDF without rendering bootstrap, the console output is:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

---

### Questions

I have two questions:

- PdfKit module is compatible with bootstrap?
- There is a way to solve my problem and download the PDF file rendered as the HTML page with the rows/columns correctly formatted?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: According to what i have been looking at, I can answer your first question. Yes it is compatible. As other questions link to using PdfKit such as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59772733/9693927

Comment: Thank you @PythonLuaMaster, probably i'm missing something in the code or something else.

Comment: No problem, hope you figure it out.

Comment: Can you open your browser's DevTools and check that the browser can find `bootstrap.min.css` on the `test_pdf_report.html` page. I suspect that something's going wrong with the path that `url_for` generates seing that Bootstrap is successfully loaded when you don't use `url_for`.

Comment: Hi @SimeonNedkov, If I open the DevTools and inspect the page `<head>` I can see `<link href="http://10.10.4.195/static/content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` so `url_for` is correctly working. Opening the url http://10.10.4.195/static/content/bootstrap.min.css I can see my boostrap file. There is no error in console.

Comment: Good! So the problem is that the columns should be aligned to the right of the page, correct?

Comment: [This is the expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJS28.png) PDF output. The bootstrap default view for rows/columns

Comment: please can you help me make the TOC? i believe i need to pass `toc = {'xsl-style-sheet': 'toc.xsl'}`, but i don't know what is supposed to go in that file...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem today. In addition I observed that it did load and use some of bootstrap. Like you, all my columns were renderings as full width. I believe I found that the issue was actually in wkhtmltopdf. It seems to have a problem with the media queries. This doesn't solve them problem but it explains what is happening. Some people have found work arounds for their specific situations but I haven't found one that works for me at this point.

[Converting Twitter bootstrap page into PDF with wkhtmltopdf : span issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705880/converting-twitter-bootstrap-page-into-pdf-with-wkhtmltopdf-span-issue)

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/258

UPDATE

I was able to downgrade to Bootstrap 3 and update my markup to account for this change in class names and had much better results. I believe the problem is the addition of Flexbox in Bootstrap 4 which isn't working in wkhtmltopdf

Comment: The problem still exists with Bootstrap 5. Following @Nexeh, I used Bootstrap 3 with wkhtmltopdf from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ instead of the pre-packaged one for Debian.